# Where to put config.yml in an R package

Tags: r, config, r-package

I am creating an R package that uses the [config](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/config/vignettes/introduction.html) package to read a `config.yml` file.

My question is: where does `config.yml` go? `config.get()` expects it to be in the root directory, so if I put it at `<my_package>/config.yml`, it locates it with no problem. However, `devtools::check()` hates this:

> Non-standard file/directory found at top level:
> 'config.yml'

The closest [explanation](https://community.rstudio.com/t/where-would-you-put-a-config-yml-file-when-building-a-package/132653/7) I've seen for what you are supposed to do only applies to when the config file is only used for unit tests. That's not my case; I need this config to actually be used by the package itself. I know I *could* fix this by just putting it in a directory like `<my_package>/R/` and replacing every invocation of `config::get()` with something like `config::get(here::here('R/config.yml'))`, but that seems hacky.

Is there a recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Goes under `inst/`.  Access the actual location with

```r
system.file('config.yml', package = '<my_package>', mustWork = TRUE)
```

Comment: Ah, now I get what that is for; thank you!